# UPDATE SET REPLACE function SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I keep getting errors when using the REPLACE function in SQL and i don't know why?

I execute this query:

```
UPDATE [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Views]
SET [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Views].SerializedProperties = REPLACE(SerializedProperties,'|EKZ PSG met verkort EEG','|EKZ PSG met verkort EEG|EEG kort op EEG3')  
WHERE [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Views].InternalViewID = '3F4C1E8E-DA0C-4829-B447-F6BDAD9CD505'
```

And I keep getting this message:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

- At UPDATE I give the correct table
- At SET I give the correct column
- At REPLACE I give the: (column name, 'old string', 'new string')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error is telling you problem. Why are you still using `ntext` anyway? It's been deprecated for almost 15 years now.

Comment: Also, referencing column names using 3+ part naming (4 part in your case) is also deprecated and should be avoided. Your code will stop working one day.

Comment: @GarethD while this is a clear duplicate, None of the answers in the post you've linked to gives a solution or explains the problem - the best you get is a workaround. This is why I've revoked your duplicate vote.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution is fix the data type:

```
USE ShellPlus;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Views] ALTER COLUMN SerializedProperties nvarchar(MAX);
```

Then your existing query will work. But you should also normalise that data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Views]
SET [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Views].SerializedProperties = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(SerializedPropertiesas NVarchar(MAX)),'|EKZ PSG met verkort EEG','|EKZ PSG met verkort EEG|EEG kort op EEG3') ) AS NText)
WHERE [ShellPlus].[dbo].[Views].InternalViewID = '3F4C1E8E-DA0C-4829-B447-F6BDAD9CD505'
```

Comment: You should really get rid of that 4 part column naming.

Comment: While this workaround will probably help the OP get rid of the error messages, it is by no means a solution to the problem - The errors the OP is getting are merely a symptom of the actual problem, which is the usage of the `Text` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing at least three things wrong:

1. It seems like you're storing delimited data in your column - which is a mistake. For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**
2. You're using the `Text` data type, which is deprecated since SQL Server 2008 introduced `varchar(max)` to replace it. Given the fact that we're in 2019 and the 2008 version just ended it's extended support this July, its high time to change that `Text` data type to `varchar(max)` (and if you're using the 2008 or 2008 r2 version, upgrade your SQL Server).
3. You're using four-parts identifiers for your column names (Thanks @Larnu for pointing that out in the comments). Best practice is to use two-parts identifiers for column names. Read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58607082/3094533) for a details explanation.

The solution to your problem involves refactoring the database structure - normalize what needs to be normalized, and replace of all `Text`, `NText` and `Image` with their modern replacement data types: `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)`. Also, this would be a good time to figure out if you really need to support values longer than 8000 chars (4000 for unicode values) and if not, use a more appropriate value (`max` length columns have poor performance compared to "regular" length columns).